# Multiple imports in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

In my assignment, I have to import many XSLT in a single xslt.

For example,

```
<Globalxslt> 
<call XSLT1/>
<call XSLT2/>
<call XSLT3/>
<call XSLT4/>
</Globalxslt>
```

I tried using `<xsl:import href=”URI”/>` and `<xsl:include href=”URI”/>` but I can import one of the xslt only and could not import the rest of the xslt.

Comment: How are you verifying the imports are or are not working?

Comment: Your stylesheet example doesn't appear to be a stylesheet and it's "call" elements have invalid attributes.

Answer (score 2):

<xsl:import href=”URI”/> should just work fine, as long as the system can find the stylesheet. Make sure you use the correct spelling and check if the stylesheet processor is fully supporting all XSLT functionality.

Which processor are you using, btw?
Do you realise that your code example isn't a stylesheet? It isn't even valid XML!